# Enthought Canopy no longer starts

Tags: enthought, canopy

Recently, the canopy shortcut stopped doing anything when I clicked on it. It has worked previously so when searching for help online I followed this advice: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469810-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything however this failed to open canopy and this was the contents of the command prompt window:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Eden>set pythonpath=
C:\Users\Eden>set pythonhome=
C:\Users\Eden>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
AMDAPPSDKROOT=c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
APPDATA=C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Roaming
asl.log=Destination=file
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=EDEN
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Eden
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\MicrosoftAccount
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OS=Windows_NT
Path=c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Clien
t\;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\
x86;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\
WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Sta
tic;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Int
el\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(
R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C
:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessComm
on\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\users\eden\appdata\local\e
nthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;C
:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Intel\
WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=EDEN
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=EDEN
USERNAME=Eden
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Eden
windir=C:\WINDOWS
C:\Users\Eden>cd "%localappdata%\enthought\canopy\app\"
C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App>_python.exe canopy-script.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2396, in main
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2270, in create
_bootstrapper
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2023, in __init
__
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 417, in __init_
_
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1165, in _setup
_misc_paths
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\apptools\preferences\preferences.py", line 365,
in load
config_obj = ConfigObj(file_or_filename, encoding='utf-8')
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\configobj.py", line 1229, in __init__
self._load(infile, configspec)
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\configobj.py", line 1318, in _load
raise error
ParseError: Invalid line (u'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00') (matched as neither section nor keywo
rd) at line 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "canopy-script.pyw", line 776, in <module>
File "canopy-script.pyw", line 336, in bootstrap
File "canopy-script.pyw", line 363, in chainload
File "canopy-script.pyw", line 762, in _chainload
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Canopy-script.pyw", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2421, in main
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2357, in send_b
ug_report
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 25, in
<module>
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 22, in <modul
e>
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\api.py", line 2, in <module>
from preferences_pane import PreferencesPane
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\preferences_pane.py", line 4,
in <module>
from traitsui.api import Controller
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\api.py", line 41, in <module>
from .editors.api import (BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\__init__.py", line 27, in <modu
le>
from .api import (toolkit, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\api.py", line 8, in <module>
from .array_editor import ArrayEditor
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\array_editor.py", line 27, in <
module>
import numpy
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.31
23.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from . import scimath as emath
ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

I've also tried reinstalling python and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your corrupted `preferences.ini` file in `C:\Users\Eden\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\`.

For reference, see ["Uninstalling and resetting Canopy"](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy).

Comment: Did this work for you, @ETW? If so, please seehttp://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work